# What happens when I run out of disc space for my move_uploaded_file function?

Tags: file, upload, size, limit

I'm currently building a website for users to upload photos and videos.  So far it's all good with the coding and the move_uploaded_file function is working well most of the time (other than some larger files not uploading, but that's not my issue here).

My concern is that I want to remain hopeful that one day, many people from around the world will visit my website and there will be hundreds or even thousands of uploads a week.  The move_uploaded_file uploads the files into a folder on my computer, which is fine for now.  But what if my website becomes popular and I run out of space on my hard drive for the files to be uploaded to?

The obvious answer would be to buy more hard drives, I know that, but how do I set them up?  Because when the files are retrieved from my folder to the user, it's only grabbing them from that one folder.  If I added another hard drive, how could I ensure that the files from the old folder are still getting retrieved as well as the files from the new folder are as well?

My operating system is Windows 10.

Help!

Comment: Which operating system are we talking about?

Comment: Windows 10 @HasseBjörk

Comment: Add them to a RAID 0?  Whether or not you can do so is based on the capabilities of the "controller"

Comment: @marklark how do I find out the capabilities of my controller?  and what is the controller?

Comment: In the 'Start Menu', right-click on 'Computer', select 'Properties'.  That will open a window.  On the left side, click on 'Device Manager' to open that program.  In it, click on your computer's name, click on 'Storage controllers'.  From there you should be able to see what you have to work with.

Comment: Another option would be to get an external storage device that is readily expandable, perhaps ZFS compatible.

Comment: thanks a lot @marklark